# Understanding std::function and std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I was playing arround with std::function and std::bind and I noticed something unintuitive and I would like to understand it better.

For example:

```
void fun()
{
}

void hun(std::string) 
{ 
}

int main()
{

   function<void(int)> g = &fun; //This fails as it should in my understanding.

   function<void(int)> f = std::bind(fun); //This works for reasons unknown to me     
   function<void(int, std::string)> h = std::bind(hun); //this doesn't work

return 0;
}
```

How is it possible to bind a **`function<void(int)>`** to a function that is **void()**.
I could then call f(1) and get fun().
I would like to understand how this is done. 
Going inside Microsoft Visual Studio 2012's implementation of this got me lost in a sea of unreadable macros. so that is why I ask this question here.

Comment: I am using vs2012 Express edition.

Comment: can you recommend such a site pls?

Comment: Compiles with _clang_ and _g++_ both. +1, interesting situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This is the correct behaviour - I'd rather wonder which stdlib *you* tested the `std::bind(fun)` version with, because that one is buggy. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::function and std::bind behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162402/stdfunction-and-stdbind-behavior)

Comment: @pacificator: ideone and liveworkspace have been used in the past. They have a good choice of compilers.

Comment: @Xeo: Sorry, my fault, I messed up my test case!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16172580/981959 for answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't use argument placeholders (`_1`, `_2`, ...), then any arguments passed to the function object returned from `std::bind` will just be discarded. With:

```
std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(fun, std::placeholders::_1);
```

I get a (long and ugly) error as expected.

For the people interested in Standardese:

`§20.8.9.1.2 [func.bind.bind]`

```
template<class F, class... BoundArgs>
*unspecified* bind(F&& f, BoundArgs&&... bound_args);
```

> p3 Returns: A forwarding call wrapper `g` with a weak result type (20.8.2). The effect of `g(u1, u2, ..., uM)` shall be `INVOKE(fd, v1, v2, ..., vN, result_of<FD cv (V1, V2, ..., VN)>::type)`, where *cv* represents the *cv*-qualifiers of `g` **and the values and types of the bound arguments `v1, v2, ..., vN` are determined as specified below**.
>
> p10 The values of the bound arguments `v1, v2, ..., vN` and their corresponding types `V1, V2, ..., VN` **depend on the types `TiD` derived from the call to `bind`** and the *cv*-qualifiers *cv* of the call wrapper `g` as follows:
>
> - if `TiD` is `reference_wrapper<T>`, the argument is `tid.get()` and its type `Vi` is `T&`;
> - if the value of `is_bind_expression<TiD>::value` is `true`, the argument is `tid(std::forward<Uj>(uj)...)` and its type `Vi` is `result_of<TiD cv (Uj...)>::type`;
> - if the value `j` of `is_placeholder<TiD>::value` is not zero, the argument is `std::forward<Uj>(uj)` and its type `Vi` is `Uj&&`;
> - otherwise, the value is `tid` and its type `Vi` is `TiD cv &`.

Comment: Further to that, even if std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(fun); compiles. It is not possible to actually call f: f(); fails to compile.

Comment: @PeterR: Obviously, because the signature to `f` mandates one argument. :)

Answer (score 6):

The forwarding call wrapper generated by a call to function template `bind` can accept any number of extra parameters; these will be ignored.  The effective arity and minimal signature of a `bind` expression is determined by the `placeholder`s used in its construction, and which callable argument(s) they are bound to.