# Binding functions with different signatures

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

If this question has been asked, I apologize.

I thought you couldn't bind functions with a different signature, but look at this:

```
void TakesChar(char parameter)
{
    std::cout << parameter << std::endl;
}

using CallSig = void(float);
using CallBack = std::function<CallSig>;

int main()
{
    CallBack callback = std::bind(&TakesChar, std::placeholders::_1);
    callback(1.1f);
    callback(2.2f);

    return 0;
}
```

That compiles and runs. You can try different parameter types and numbers. You can, for instance, modify `TakesChar` so that it takes no parameters, and it will still compile.

Why is this? Is there a rationale behind it? And can I enforce signatures to match exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the signature parameter of `std::function` only concerns its own interface. The encapsulated function (object) can have any signature as long as a call is possible after conversions. Besides, one cannot possibly extract a signature from a function object with an `operator()` template. In your case, I think a `float` is just converted to `char`.

Comment: `float` is convertible to `char`. If `TakesChar`'s parameter was some type for which an implicit conversion from `float` didn't exist, your code wouldn't compile. That last part about modifying `TakesChar` so it takes no arguments is only true if you also remove `_1` from the `bind` call. You cannot bind placeholders to non-existent parameters. If you do both, then you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the resulting callable. The reason for that is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13252595/241631).

Comment: The code would be more readable with less `typedef`s, specially in a short question like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are two questions here:

1. Why is conversion allowed ?
2. Why if no argument is provided to `bind`, the return object accepts any number of argument ?

The former is just a decision on the behavior of `bind`: since you can call `TakesChar(1.1f)` why not allow `std::bind(&TakesChar, _1)` to bind to `std::function<void(float)>` ? The committee decided to allow it.

The latter, as explained in comments, was already addressed on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13251976/147192). In short, not only is it easier, it also allows to `bind` an object that has multiple `operator()` of different arities.