# Is template type of a std::function detached by std::bind an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, stdbind

i am working on MSVC

```
static bool filter_entity(void* entity)
{
    return entity == nullptr;
};
template<typename F>
static bool Dispatch(const F& filter)
{
    return filter(nullptr);
};
int main()
{
    void* ptr = new int();
    if (Dispatch(std::bind(&filter_entity, ptr))) cout << "nullptr" << endl;
    else cout << "intptr" << endl;
    //ret: intptr
}
```

it is weird that invoking a function with the const `nullptr` argument actually insert the `ptr` as argument, i wonder if it is an undefined behaviour.

Also is there a way to call `filter()` for this instance and make the template and `std::bind` significant for multiple situations?

Comment: `std::bind(&filter_entity, ptr)` is roughly equivalent to `[ptr](const auto&...){ return filter_entity(ptr); }` (with an unused `const auto&...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to [the bound object] are not matched by any placeholders stored in [the bound object], the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.

The bound object from the question has no placeholders. So the `nullptr` in

```
return filter(nullptr);
```

is evaluated and discarded, and the result is the same as if

```
return filter();
```

was called. If we interpret the binding, this is the same as

```
return filter_entity(ptr);
```

(or would be if `ptr` was in scope). If you want to use the `nullptr` in the return statement, you would need to use `std::placeholders::_1` in your `std::bind`.

---

A followup question to this might be [Why do objects returned from bind ignore extra arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251976/why-do-objects-returned-from-bind-ignore-extra-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

Stop using `std::bind`.  `std::bind` is not worth becoming an expert in.  Become an expert in lambdas instead.

`std::bind` was imported from `boost::bind` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) at the same time lambdas arrived.  It was a library solution that lambdas solved many of the same problems as it did.  In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) `std::bind` could do a few things lambdas could not; since then lambda became more poeerful, and this is no longer true.

`std::bind` is full of strange corners.  You are witnessing one of them; honestly one of the more pedestrian ones.

---

`std::bind` does not return a `std::function`.  `std::bind` returns an unnamed object with an `operator()`.  When you call the `operator()` on it, it first grabs its bound arguments (eith some unwrapping of references), does some rerouting based on placeholders and bound subexpressions,.

After a complex step there, it then "silently" discards extra arguments.

So you bound the first argument to nullptr; the later non null is evsluated and discarded.